# What in my CS code is making my right column drop down when with smaller screen size?

Tags: css

When I resize my window to 1280 x 720 or below I just realized I'm getting some behavior I do not want. The right column (.right class) is getting "bumped down" below when I resize my window

What is it in my CSS code (or not in the code) that's causing this? I have a feeling that I'm missing a very important concept here. :)

Here is what happens to the right column on smaller screens: http://s11.postimg.org/vp9c7o3dv/css.png

And here is the faulty code:
http://codepen.io/cosmonaut/pen/yyvZjZ?editors=110

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://s16.postimg.org/k5re12691/bg_radium.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
 width: 95%;
 font-family: courier;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #E7DFC2;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 10px auto;
 background-color: #273E23;
 opacity: 0.97;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.header {
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray; /* Temporary. */
 background-color: #273E23;
}

.header p {
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 0px; 
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #273E23;

}

.header img {
 padding: 0px; 
 margin: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

.menu {
 text-align: center;

}

.menu ul {
}

.menu ul li {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;

}

.menu ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #273E23;
 color: #D3B474;
}

.left {
 float: left;
 width: 160px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1em;
}

.right {
 padding: 1em;
 float: right;
 width: 860px;
 background-color: #273E23;;
}

.right p {
 background-color: #273E23;
}

.footer {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: .5em;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #273E23;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet_v2.css"/>
 <title>Radium Recordings</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/z08mz7o9f/radium4.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="left"><p>Hi, I'm the left side. Not sure if I'm even going to keep this column. Lorem Ipsum added: 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia tellus vel nunc accumsan maximus. Pellentesque justo sem, condimentum non lectus sed, consequat dignissim eros. Integer id ante lectus. Nam id nisi dui. Curabitur euismod volutpat accumsan. Donec pellentesque metus eleifend, imperdiet arcu lacinia, convallis est. Curabitur porta interdum vehicula. Fusce mollis quam et ex venenatis, eget luctus risus pellentesque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia tellus vel nunc accumsan maximus. Pellentesque justo sem, condimentum non lectus sed, consequat dignissim eros. Integer id ante lectus. Nam id nisi dui. Curabitur euismod volutpat accumsan. Donec pellentesque metus eleifend, imperdiet arcu lacinia, convallis est. Curabitur porta interdum vehicula. Fusce mollis quam et ex venenatis, eget luctus risus pellentesque.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia tellus vel nunc accumsan maximus. Pellentesque justo sem, condimentum non lectus sed, consequat dignissim eros. Integer id ante lectus. Nam id nisi dui. Curabitur euismod volutpat accumsan. Donec pellentesque metus eleifend, imperdiet arcu lacinia, convallis est. Curabitur porta interdum vehicula. Fusce mollis quam et ex venenatis, eget luctus risus pellentesque.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia tellus vel nunc accumsan maximus. Pellentesque justo sem, condimentum non lectus sed, consequat dignissim eros. Integer id ante lectus. Nam id nisi dui. Curabitur euismod volutpat accumsan. Donec pellentesque metus eleifend, imperdiet arcu lacinia, convallis est. Curabitur porta interdum vehicula. Fusce mollis quam et ex venenatis, eget luctus risus pellentesque.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lacinia tellus vel nunc accumsan maximus. Pellentesque justo sem, condimentum non lectus sed, consequat dignissim eros. Integer id ante lectus. Nam id nisi dui. Curabitur euismod volutpat accumsan. Donec pellentesque metus eleifend, imperdiet arcu lacinia, convallis est. Curabitur porta interdum vehicula. Fusce mollis quam et ex venenatis, eget luctus risus pellentesque.</p>
   <p>Aliquam convallis nulla commodo convallis scelerisque. Curabitur elementum porttitor purus, posuere tincidunt turpis sagittis et. Proin non nulla vitae velit rutrum egestas id vitae dolor. Mauris placerat nec metus vel ultrices. Integer molestie lobortis eros a dapibus. Pellentesque commodo iaculis magna fringilla rhoncus. Nullam luctus dui elit, nec ornare erat volutpat vitae. Vestibulum nulla velit, porttitor in hendrerit vel, varius sit amet elit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <p>P.O. Box 321, Anywhere, USA 31721 | Tel: (888) 888-8888</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The simple fact that there’s not enough space to display those elements next to each other, given the element dimensions and paddings you have specified …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your column widths to percentages. One example is [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/bobdye/pen/ogERjg).

I used:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
.right {
    padding: 1em;
    float: right;
    width: 67%;
    background-color: #273E23;;
}
```

but you can use any percentages that look right to you.

Comment: Nice! That worked great! Using px for height and width instead of percentages must be a really bad idea. Thank you!

Comment: Well, at least when you are trying to make a responsive design, using percentages for widths is important.

Comment: @bobdye In Stack you should not provide solution straight away. Instead of doing that you should put an explanation so that if someone else face this problem in future, then they can get help from here. You should keep explanation "Why the code wasn't working?"

Comment: Thanks again. As far as I'm concerned this is good enough. I do notice that when I check for mobile "view" (320x480) is starts to mess up again. If I wanted to fix that as well, what's the best practice on fixing how it looks on a mobile phone? Keep adjusting the % values until it looks good or is there another, better way? Again, this is good enough for what I need for now so thank you. I'll make sure to always remember this in the future.

Comment: Use a media query like @media (min-width: 400px) {} to enclose new CSS rules for that size. What is quite typical is, for mobile, to set the column widths to 100% and remove any float. This means that they will be stacked vertically instead of being side-by-side.

Comment: Looks like I have ALOT more to learn about good responsive design. :) I'll look into the @media query, along what the other things once I have a little more free time. Thanks again for the reply back!

Answer (score 0):

You have two column in your site. One have class name "left" another have class named "right". Now each of those class have fixed width. So when the screen size goes less than the declared width the 2nd column get down to get it desire size.

If we see the explanation:

```
.right {
   padding: 1em;
   float: right;
   width: 860px;
   background-color: #273E23;
}
.left {
   float: left;
   width: 160px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 1em;
}
```

Here we can see **right** class have width of 860px and the **left** class have width of 160px. Also the **right** class have a padding of 1em which is 15 in pixel. So if you want to show both of the element in single line then the minimum screen size should be 1050px (860 + 30 + 160). Here 30 is summation of both side padding 15 px.

If you want to do the code in such way that you what ever the screen size is both column should maintain size ratio then instead of using fixed width you should use %. For batter understanding you can check example of @bobdye

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

On small screen you have not enough space in `.container` for two columns.

You should set `.container` width in `px`, or declare `min-width` for it, or declare width of left and right columns in `%`.